# why my code is always giving the same result i.e ' the string is not a palindrome'

Tags: python, string, comparison, palindrome

my code always give the same result i.e. 'the string is not a palindrome'
why is this happening?
but the reversing of string is working properly

```
original = input('enter string: ')
index = len(original) - 1
reverse_string =" "
while index >= 0 :
    reverse_string += original[index]
    index = index - 1

print('reverse string:', reverse_string)

if (reverse_string == original):
     print("it's a palindrome:")
else:
     print("it's not a palindrome:")
```

Comment: `reverse_string =" "` You're initialising your string with an extra space.

Comment: `reverse_string = '' ` so that the string is instantiated without a whitespace

Comment: An alternative way to check palindrome string : `original == original[::-1]`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you start your `reverse_string` with a space (i.e. `" "`):

```
original = input('enter string: ')
index = len(original) - 1
reverse_string = ""
while index >= 0 :
    reverse_string += original[index]
    index = index - 1

print('reverse string:', reverse_string)

if (reverse_string == original):
     print("it's a palindrome:")
else:
     print("it's not a palindrome:")
```

Also you can shorten it to:

```
original = input('enter string: ')
if (original == original[::-1]): # [::-1] Returns the string in reverse.
     print("it's a palindrome:")
else:
     print("it's not a palindrome:")
```

Per the comments you could also shorten this more if you wanted (by olinox14):

```
original = input('enter string: ')
print("It's {}a palindrome".format("not " * (original!= original[::-1])))
```

or the more readable (by Matthias):

```
original = input('enter string: ')
print("It's{}a palindrome".format(' ' if original==original[::-1] else ' not '))
```

Comment: You could even do: `print("Is a palindrome:", original == original[::-1])`

Comment: True, I was just matching his current output.

Comment: I know, that was just for the pleasure. Also: `print("It's {}a palindrome".format("not " * (original!= original[::-1])))`

Comment: That's a creative way to use string multiplication....

Comment: I prefer the more readable `print("It's{}a palindrome".format(' ' if original==original[::-1] else ' not '))`

Comment: Okay I added them because they are creative :)

Answer (score 0):

You are initialising `reverse_string` as `" "` so this string will always have an additional space and will never be equal to the original.

But you can simplify your code as:

`reverse_string = ''.join(reversed(original))`

or:

`reverse_string = original[::-1]`